# Views trying show term node count/comment count/latest post

Tags: 7, views

I got a taxonomy called forum and several terms. I crated a view to show the terms http://missioncity.ca/forums In the display I'm trying to show Term Name | Content Count | Comment Count | Latest Topic.

I got all of that data cells showing but I can't get the proper Comment Count (I want to show a total of all comments from all posts) and to show the latest posted topic.

I'm trying this to not have to use the forums module and be able to use different content types in this pseduo forum.

This is my view

```
    $view = new view();
$view->name = 'forums';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$view->human_name = 'Forums';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Forums';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['distinct'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class'] = '.col-xs-12';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['inline'] = array(
  'name_1' => 'name_1',
  'name' => 'name',
  'title' => 'title',
  'comment_count' => 'comment_count',
  'nothing' => 'nothing',
);
/* Relationship: Taxonomy term: Content with term */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['table'] = 'taxonomy_index';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['id'] = 'title_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Field: COUNT(DISTINCT Content: Nid) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['group_type'] = 'count_distinct';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['id'] = 'name_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['link_to_taxonomy'] = TRUE;
/* Field: COUNT(Taxonomy term: Name) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['group_type'] = 'count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['empty'] = '(0)';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
/* Field: COUNT(Content: Title) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['group_type'] = 'count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['path'] = 'business-pages/%1/[name_1]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['path_case'] = 'lower';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['prefix'] = 'Posts ';
/* Field: Content: Comment count */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['id'] = 'comment_count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['table'] = 'node_comment_statistics';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['field'] = 'comment_count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['label'] = 'Comments ';
/* Field: Global: Custom text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['id'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['text'] = 'Latest Topic: [title_1]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Comment count */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count_1']['id'] = 'comment_count_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count_1']['table'] = 'node_comment_statistics';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count_1']['field'] = 'comment_count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count_1']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count_1']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Sort criterion: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['name']['field'] = 'name';
/* Filter criterion: Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['id'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['field'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['value'] = array(
  'forum' => 'forum',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_forum');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'forums';
```

This is my view. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Comment counter](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_counter)

> This is a tiny module that basically extends Drupal's comment
>   statistics module by adding comment counts for day, week, month and
>   year. It also integrates with Views and you can use it to select,
>   filter, order the content as well.